# IOS 7 how to use UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to IOS 7 and I'm made a test application where I want to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath when a left swipe is detected. The swipe is detected but I'm struggling with the "self" definition.
I get the error No visible @interface for 'SimpleTableViewController'

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"%u = %d",  recognizer.direction,recognizer.state);

     // jump to section 0 row 20 when leftswipe is dectected
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:20 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

}
```

I can send the complete source code if you want or you can download it here:

www.auditext.com/xintax/SimpleTable.zip

Using self.tableView gives message Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'SimpleTableViewController' –

It works now I have added this line to my viewcontroller.h:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myview;

NSIndexPath *loc = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

[self.myview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:loc atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
`

Comment: Post the code that is actually giving you the error and point out the exact line causing the problem.

Comment: And include the *complete* error message.

Comment: Where is this code? Is this in the code of a custom table view cell class or in the code for your view controller?

Comment: @user3369041, You need to declare property of UITableView in your header file. Check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to point to the `UItableView`

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath 
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                              animated:NO];
```

[image]

Comment: When I use self.tableView I go the message Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'SimpleTableViewController'

Comment: @user3369041 if you dont have a uitableviewcontroller then create an outlet to the UItableView

Comment: It works now I have added this to my viewcontroller.h file:   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myview;

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call is self.tableView instead of self.
self refers to the TableViewController and self.tableView to it's tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are getting this error, Because `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` is a `UITableView` method Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition%3a).

And also you are calling the same method with `self` which indicate you class name `SimpleTableViewController`. So you are getting this error `No visible @interface for 'SimpleTableViewController'`. Just call this method with `self.tableView` instead of using `self`.

Note:-

1) Declare property inside your header file `SimpleTableViewController`  `@property(nonatomic,strong)UITableView *tableView`

2) No need to explicitly include the synthesize, if you are using Xcode version above than 4.